# HTML5 and Canvas/createImageData

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I just have a question about memory allocation with ImageData in HTML. When you call createImageData, it apparently creates an Object. My question is, when does that object get deleted from memory, and is there a function to delete such objects? If not, would using it in a function with a local variable delete the object on the functions exit?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It will be deleted when there are no references to it and it goes out of scope, so yes a local variable in a function would be freed when the function returns (so long as you haven't created a reference to it elsewhere). You can free it early by assigning the object null.

Comment: @user1920386 if this answered your question you should consider marking it as accepted (a tick right below the counter upper left corner of answer).